# Resize Serializable List size (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist, serializable

Currently I have a serializable class called QuestionAnswers with the following :

```
public string question;
public string[] answers;
public int correctAnswer;
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class QuestionAnswers
{
public string question;
public string[] answers;
public int correctAnswer;
}
```

---

In my normal MonoBehaviour script called ListManager I reference the serializable class called QuestionAnswers as QnA:

```
public List<QuestionAnswers> QnA;
```

---

```
public class ListManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public List<QuestionAnswers> QnA;
```

---

in the inspector the public List QnA shows as below

[Inspector image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2FEJ.jpg)

My question is how can I change the QnA size value (currently 1, as shown above) and the Answers Size value (currently 4, as shown above) in my ListManger script via an inputfield.text field.

Note that the structure of the List QnA(as shown above) should stay the same as the correct answer value is connected to the answers and the answers is connected to the question.

Example :

When I increase the QnA size value to say 3 the inspector shows following :

[Inspector Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POiyL.jpg)
(Note the arrows to the left of each element)

when I click on each element the inspector show the following :

[Inspector Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzf81.jpg)
(note the arrows to the left of each Answer)

When I click on the Answers the inspector show the following:
[Inspector Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBNJF.jpg)
(I have added the value 4 next to each Answer in the inspector)

Just to recap on my question :

How can I change the QnA size value (currently 1, as shown above) and the Answers Size value (currently 4, as shown above) in my ListManger script via an inputfield.text field.

Note that the structure of the `List<QuestionAnswers> QnA`(as shown above) should stay the same as the correct answer value is connected to the answers and the answers is connected to the question.

Comment: `via an inputfield.text field` do you mean you want a UI input field element in your scene, that lets you change the size of your list?

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 0):

It is a list so you can simply [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add) and [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat) entries until the list has the size you want like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] InputField input;

private void Start ()
{
    input.contentType = ContentType.IntegerNumber;
    input.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChanged);
}

private void OnInputValueChanged(string newInput)
{
    if(!int.TryParse(newInput, out var newCount)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"\"{newInput}\" is no valid number!", this);
        return;
    }

    if(newCount < 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Negative values are not allowed!", this);
        return;
    }

    if(newCount == QnA.Count)
    {
        Debug.Log("Already same count", this);
        return;
    }

    while(newCount > QnA.Count)
    {
        QnA.Add(new QuestionAnswers());
    }

    while(newCount < QnA.Count)
    {
        QnA.RemoveAt(QnA.Count - 1);
    }   
}
```

Or simply create a new list with the correct size like

```
private void OnInputValueChanged(string newInput)
{
    if(!int.TryParse(newInput, out var newCount)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"\"{newInput}\" is no valid number!", this);
        return;
    }
    if(newCount < 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Negative values are not allowed!", this);
        return;
    }

    if(newCount == QnA.Count)
    {
        Debug.Log("Already same count", this);
        return;
    }

    QnA = new QuestionAnswers[newCount].ToList();
}
```

Depends a lot on your exact use case.

---

The answers would automatically have the size `4` if you would rather already initialize them by default like

```
public string[] answers = new string[4];
```

Comment: The QnA.Add and QnA.Remove give errors as it sees the QnA as an array and not a list

Comment: @DesertFoxx in your question it is clearly a `List<QuestionAnswers>` and definitely **not** an array ... we can only provide answers based on the code you provide ... Btw in the second solution I already have exactly what you are doing in your answer now ... Except I already told you how to get the value from the InputField instead and if yours is an array - then simply skip the `ToList()` call ...

Answer (score -1):

I think I solved the problem.

This is my code for the serializable list called QnA

```
    int newsize = 3 (This value will eventually come from an inputfield)   
    
    [Serializable]
    private class QnA
    {
        public string question;
        public string[] answers;
        public int correctAnswer;
    }
```

Then I made a serializedField like this

```
[SerializeField] private QnA[] qnaArray;
```

In my Start function in just did the following

```
public void Start()
{
    qnaArray = new QnA[newsize];

}
```

So when I run the application the QnA size automatically change to the newsize int value.
I will now continue to try and change the answer value through the code and implement the inputfield to replace the newsize int.

Thanks for everyone's assistance.
It is much appreciated.

Comment: Next question is how do I access the public string[] answer in the serializable class to change its value.